# How to show the currents char code in ruler

Tags: encoding, ruler

I want the ruler made to show the current characters code. This code differs from encoding to encoding.

This is because I have to handle different file comming from users. Some from Unix/Linux, most from Windows.

Concerning `VIM version 8.0.1453`

(I use vim to write perl skripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example under `:help statusline`:

```
<   Similar, but add ASCII value of char under the cursor (like "ga") >
      :set statusline=%<%f%h%m%r%=%b\ 0x%B\ \ %l,%c%V\ %P
```

It's "Emulat[ing] [the] standard status line with 'ruler' set" and "add[ing] ASCII value of char under the cursor."

The relevant items are

```
    b N   Value of character under cursor.
    B N   As above, in hexadecimal.
```

---

As Christian Brabandt points out, you can set just the ruler with `rulerformat`, which takes similar items. For example,

```
:set rulerformat=%b\ 0x%B\ %c%V\ %p%%
```

---

**Note** (see vim-help,`:h ruler`):
"If the statusline is given by 'statusline' ... this option takes precedence over 'ruler' and 'rulerformat'"

Comment: you might want to mention, that you can also set the ruler using `:set rulerformat`

Comment: I don't think so